# Select IDs in pivot table including multiple pivot ID and excluding one pivot ID

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, having

How can I select the products that are in two categories and removing one category?

Example: I wish to select only the products that are in the category one and category two, excluding the category three.

A product has to have both category one and two.

If a product has the category one, two and three is excluded.

I was trying to do something like this but it doesn't work:

```sql
SELECT products.product_id , products.product_name FROM products
INNER JOIN product_category_relations ON product_category_relations.relations_product_id = products.product_id
WHERE relations_category_id IN (1,2) AND relations_category_id  NOT IN (3)
GROUP BY products.product_id
```

Product_id selected: 1 and 2.

**Example Products Table**

| product_id | product_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | tshirt |
| 2 | pants |
| 3 | Bikini |
| 4 | Jumper |

**Example categories Table**

| category_id | category_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | category one |
| 2 | category two |
| 3 | category three |
| 4 | category four |

**Pivot product_category_relations Table**

| relations_category_id | relations_product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `WHERE` clause include all 3 categories and use the `HAVING` clause to exclude category 3:

```
SELECT p.product_id , p.product_name 
FROM products p INNER JOIN product_category_relations pcr
ON pcr.relations_product_id = p.product_id
WHERE pcr.relations_category_id IN (1, 2, 3) 
GROUP BY p.product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- only 2 categories are allowed
   AND SUM(pcr.relations_category_id = 3) = 0 -- exclude category 3
```

Or, simplify the `HAVING` clause with `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(pcr.relations_category_id ORDER BY pcr.relations_category_id) = '1,2'
```